# How to move document between 2 different collection in Firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to "move" a document from one collection to another in Firestore. That means copy/paste a document and then delete the original. I'm trying to achieve this server-side using Python.

I'm aware that I should use transactions, so I implemented one. When I run the script, I can see in Firestore that the document I targeted was indeed deleted from the old collection, and a new document has been created in the new one.

Success ?

How can I test the transaction I coded ? I'm a little confused with the transaction logic itself. In particular, I'm not sure how I implemented the "copy part" in my transaction (see below). Why get() and delete() have references to the transaction but set() doesn't ?

Here's my code so far, using transaction to move a document:

```py
from google.cloud import firestore
import time

@firestore.transactional
def move_in_transaction(transaction, doc1, doc2):
    # get the data
    doc = doc1.get(transaction=transaction)
    if doc.exists:
        print(f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}')
    else:
        print(u'No such document!')

    # copy the data
    doc2.set(doc.to_dict())
    # delete the original
    transaction.delete(doc.reference)


def main():
    db = firestore.Client()
    transaction = db.transaction()
    doc1 = db.collection(u'AAA').document(u'111')
    doc2 = db.collection(u'BBB').document(u'111')

    transaction_attempts = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # apply transaction
            move_in_transaction(transaction, doc1, doc2)
            print("Successfully applied transaction")
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Could not apply transaction. Error: {e}")
            time.sleep(5)
            transaction_attempts += 1
            if transaction_attempts > 10:
                print(f"Stop trying transactions")
                exit()
```

It does the job, but I'm not sure about the "Copy part" in the transaction itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your `doc2.set(doc.to_dict())` happens outside of the transaction. This means that `doc1` could be modified (and the transaction retried), but `doc2` would already have been written. The final state would probably be correct (as `doc2` will get updated on the retry of the transaction), but you'll temporarily have a state where both `doc1` and `doc2` exist, and have different contents. As in my answer to your previous question: it's up to you to determine whether this is acceptable or not.

If you want the writing of `doc2` to happen as part of the transaction, there's a `transaction.set(...)` method in the SDK too. See
https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/transaction.html

Comment: Alright got it ! I changed the set() to : ```transaction.set(doc2, doc.to_dict())```. Thanks @Frank